# Can't find find out why it doesn't compile

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to add this [**ECS**](https://github.com/pvigier/ecs) into my code. I get the following error when I try to compile:

> /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Roguelike.dir/Game.cpp.o: in function 'ecs::generateComponentType()':
> /home/luc/programming/cpp/RogueLikeCPP/ecs/Components/Component.h:17: multiple definition of 'ecs::generateComponentType()'; CMakeFiles/Roguelike.dir/Engine.cpp.o:/home/luc/programming/cpp/RogueLikeCPP/ecs/Components/Component.h:17: first defined here

Here is my github [repo](https://github.com/Aganthor/RoguelikeCPP).

#### The file in question:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstddef>

namespace ecs {

//
//Generic Component. A automatic Type ID is generated fdor each.
//

template <typename T>
class Component {
public:
    static const std::size_t type;
};

std::size_t generateComponentType() {
    static auto counter = std::size_t(0);
    return counter++;
}

template <typename T>
const std::size_t Component<T>::type = generateComponentType();
  
} // namespace ecs
```

The curious part is that if I clone his repo, everything compiles fine.

I'm running Linux with gcc version 9.1.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this code is just broken. It only works if you include `Component.h` in at most one `.cpp` file.

Comment: Use `inline std::size_t generateComponentType()  ...` or move it to a .cpp file.

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov, I don't think that will be a problem. An `inline` function may have function `static` variables.

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov, not true. The compiler/linker are required to do the right thing to make sure that there is only one instance of the function `static` variable.

Comment: Presumably by not actually inlining the function. Which they are allowed to do.

Comment: Thanks R Sahu. Added the inline keyword and it’s now compiling fine.

Comment: You're correct; I misread that answer and am preparing a comment requesting clarification/rewording there. (for the curious, my specific compiler emitted a weak symbol for the function and a unique global symbol (GNU extension) for the variable)